# How to detect text enters in the CTR+F input box

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How we can find text enters in the CTR+F input box with the core javascript?

In this screenshot, I have searched `Of course` text.

How we can find `Of course` text?

[image]

Comment: Is your concern only to to detect the text or you want to identify the search box also?

Comment: @Dip686 yes, detect text only or if is there a way to add a listener on that input box that would be great?

Comment: if you want to test whether the text is only present or not you can try window.find(),
if You want to get all the elements, try document.querySelectorAll or Jquery's :contains().

Comment: @Dip686 I want to find that text user has entered in the CTR+F input box.

Comment: Well i don't think there is any way to identify the text inside search box of browser, what you may do, use keypress event to detect ctrl+f pressed or not, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress, keycode, which, key properties will be helpful.

Comment: keypress is helpful but I want to find entered text but that' okay. Thank you so much for your help @Dip686

Answer (score 3):

In general, you cannot invoke browser controls from inside the webpage - security, sandboxing, and all that.
A trick could be listening to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> , `prevent` it and then capture all the keys user enters then do what you want to do .

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) { 
        callBackCtrlF();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

then you could use :

```
function callBackCtrlF() {
     // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: `if(!test_key(keylist[i]))` test_key function is not defined.

Comment: @PankajThakur I updated my answer , previous code has some mistakes